# How to create a CIDR/Subnet Mask from a list of IPv4 IPs

Tags: python, ip-address, cidr

I'm trying to build a list of CIDRs built from a list of varying IPv4 addresses quickly and figured I could automate the process faster with python. I'm looking for a library/module/process that could convert a list of varying addresses like so:

```
['192.168.0.0', '192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2', '192.168.0.3', '10.0.0.0', '10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2', '10.0.0.3']
```

Into CIDR notation for each subnet:

```
['192.168.0.0/30', '10.0.0.0/30']
```

**Note**
Some of the IPs will be varied (as in they are not going to be entirely sequential) , for example, `['192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.4']`.  if possible, I'd like for these address to fall within a subnet for the entire octet, like `/24, /16, /8`.

Any libraries or processes out there that could help me out with something like this?

Comment: How does your proposed process decide that `192.168.0.3` and `10.0.0.1` should be separated in the output?  Why is your answer not `0.0.0.0/0`?

Comment: @IanMcLaird I'm not certain I understand your question properly, but I was thinking of using the `netaddr` library to differentiate the ip blocks somehow

Comment: Also want to know how to do this in python. May need to specify a max-aggregation - ie class A B C. CMU has a tool that does this: `rwsetcat talkers.set --network-structure=C` would yield class C aggregations -  https://tools.netsa.cert.org/silk/rwsetcat.html https://github.com/redjack/silk/blob/master/src/rwset/rwsetcat.c